# How to do an array formula with a structured reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I need to calculate the `MEDIAN` of the rows matching some conditions.

Conditions are in the rows A, B, C and D and my infos are in a table called `classic_v2_log`. When I'm using the Sheet Name it works:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((ClassicRAW!B:B=A35)*(ClassicRAW!C:C=B35)*(ClassicRAW!D:D=C35)*(ClassicRAW!E:E=D35),ClassicRAW!F:F))
```

But if I try to use the Table reference it gives me a `#N/A` and if I try to use the `Show Calculation Steps` it goes beyond the Table.

I'm trying something like this and it's not working:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((classic_v2_Log[ [ Epochs] ]=A35),ClassicRAW!F:F))
```

I am confirming the formula with Ctrl+Shift+ENTER to make it as an array-formula.

Comment: Your ranges probably need to be the same size.

Comment: But when I'm doing `=MEDIAN(IF((classic_v2_Log[ [ Epochs] ]=A35),ClassicRAW!F:F))` it's just one range and the `#N/A` is still there.

Comment: But the first range is part of a table, say 50 rows, and the second reference is a whole column (outside the table?). Make it the same and that should work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, can you please write it as an Answer so I can set it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential point is that the two ranges (arrays) need to be the same size. If one of the ranges is in a table and the other isn't you will have to ensure the second is the same number of rows as the first.

For example, if your table ran from row 2 to row 50:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((classic_v2_Log[ [ Epochs] ]=A35),ClassicRAW!F2:F50))
```